# parted says: Error: Can't have overlapping partitions

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I printed my partition table by `parted`:

```
Number  Start     End       Size     Type      File system     Flags
 1      0.03MB    64429MB   64429MB  primary   ntfs            boot
        64429MB   64429MB   0.09MB             Free Space
 2      64429MB   65452MB   1023MB   primary   ext4
 3      65452MB   115452MB  50000MB  primary   ext4
        115452MB  115453MB  1.05MB             Free Space
 4      115453MB  179453MB  64000MB  extended
 5      115453MB  165453MB  49999MB  logical   ext4
 6      165454MB  175453MB  9999MB   logical   ext4
        175453MB  175453MB  0.47MB             Free Space
 7      175454MB  179453MB  3999MB   logical   linux-swap(v1)
        179453MB  250059MB  70606MB            Free Space
```

the 179453 - 250059 is free space. But when I tried to make a partition on it:

```
(parted) mkpart logical ext4 179455 250059
Error: Can't have overlapping partitions. 

(parted) mkpart logical ext4 179455MB 250059MB
Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.
```

I got an error. Which partition is overlapped?

Answer (score 1):

got it!

My extended partition is too small. I resized it to th whole rest disk. All works well.